# Can I use lmer if my experiments include 4 latin square blocks in a single experiment?

Tags: lme4-nlme, experiment-design, latin-square

(Please understand I am a real novice)
I ran an experiment to investigate the interaction between factors. I used 6 factors, namely A,B,C,D,E,F.
The whole experiment has 5 blocks and each block by itself is a 2X2 latin square design. In other words, my experiment consists of 5 latin square design experiments (2 of A X 2 of B, 2 of A X 2 of C, and same for AXD, AXE, AXF, the numbers of levels in each factor is 2 in all conditions).

My question is whether I can use lmer or lmertest in R to evaluate the interaction between the two factors in each block. If yes, what function should I use?

If not, is it possible to splice each block and run lmer for each block as a separate experiment?

I would so much appreciate it if I could get any comments and suggestions!!

Comment: If you want good feedback, a reproducible example would be very helpful.  This doesn't have to use your actual data (if it's private), but instead use simulated data.  Ideally show your entire design, but replace the response values with random(fake) data.  See this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example